# 4.3inch-dsi-lcd jamming RPI4 wifi signal

Tags: wifi, pi-4, lcd

I just bought RPI4 and 4.3 display (https://www.waveshare.com/4.3inch-dsi-lcd.htm). I attached display as required but wasn't able to get wifi connected. I noticed that `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` shows some networks but just strongest ones. I was searching for solution and I found this: https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2019/himblick/raspberry-pi-4-loses-wifi-at-2560x1440-screen-resolution/ ... so I unscrewed display and placed display and RPI4 on the desk as far as possible  and wifi started to work.

Does anyone encountered that problem? It looks like wifi signal is being jammed but I do not know how to approach that problem.

Comment: Facing same issue. Wifi not connecting when 4.3 inch display is connected. Did you got any solution?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to solve it. Workaround is to just unscrew display and put it next to RPI4.

Comment: I am also using same display with Raspberry Pi 3B+. What I have observed is this problem is happening only with 2.5Ghz WiFi hotspot (created from my android phone). Didn't happened with 5GHz access point in my office.Then tried to change WiFi channel in Android hotspot settings from Auto to different values, and it start connecting if I select WiFi channels 5 and 6.